# Calculate my xml layout complexity in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Any way to check my layout complexity, I know we can use layout inspector but does the android studio offers any other inspection tool which can check if my layout is complex or not. Suggestions are welcome for any other best available tools.

Comment: Well you have Profiler in Android Studio so maybe it;'s not for measuring how XML is complex per se, but it definitely shows you if you have too much work done on the UI thread - often because of very complex UI

Comment: Thanks, @Mariusz but I'm specifically looking for layout tool. For data I know we can use the profiler.

Comment: And what do you exactly mean by saying complexity?

Comment: Hierarchical complexity, for example - using a layout structure using constraint layout inside the constraint layout vs constraint layout inside linear layout. I want to see which is complex to render on the UI and which one renders best. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: The Android [Optimizing Layout Hierarchies](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout)  and [Optimizing View Hierarchies](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies) documentation also recommends using lint and paying attention to the things it catches under the Android->Lint->Performance category.  Not the same as "calculating layout complexity" but it does at least raise these issues to the surface where you can deal with them.